# How can I use the bbm latex package through nix?

Tags: latex, nix

I have made a small nix environment to make tex documents, but it does not work as expected. I am not knowledgeable enough in either nix or latex to pin down precisely what is causing the error.

An example document is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
$x=\mathbbm{1}_{A}$
\end{document}
```

To be able to compile it, I have made the following `flake.nix` file:

```
{
  description = "latex-test-flake";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/release-23.05";
  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, ... }:
  let
    system = "x86_64-linux";
  in {
    devShells.${system}.default = let
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
    in pkgs.mkShell {
      packages = with pkgs; [
        (pkgs.texlive.combine {
          inherit (pkgs.texlive) scheme-basic bbm bbm-macros latexmk metafont;
        })
      ];
      shellHook = ''
        export LC_ALL=C
      '';
    };
  };
}
```

I enter the dev environment by executing `nix develop -i`, to not pollute the environment with other packages on my system.
When I run the compilation command `latexmk -pdf main.tex`, I get the following output:

```
Rc files read:                                                                                                                                                 
  NONE                                                                                                                                                         
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Jan. 2023. Version 4.79.                                                                                             
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.                                                                                   
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...                                                                                                                           
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun                                                                                                                            
Category 'other':                                                                                                                                              
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                               
------------                                                                                                                                                   
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'                                                                                                                                
------------                                                                                                                                                   
------------                                                                                                                                                   
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "main.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/nixos.org) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/nix/store/5z8dbwcramqp6khals7x0k7z40c8q4fy-texlive-combined-2022-texmfdist/te
x/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

(/nix/store/5z8dbwcramqp6khals7x0k7z40c8q4fy-texlive-combined-2022-texmfdist/te
x/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/nix/store/5z8dbwcramqp6khals7x0k7z40c8q4fy-texlive-combined-2022-texmfdist/te
x/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty)
(/nix/store/5z8dbwcramqp6khals7x0k7z40c8q4fy-texlive-combined-2022-texmfdist/te
x/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./main.aux)
(/nix/store/5z8dbwcramqp6khals7x0k7z40c8q4fy-texlive-combined-2022-texmfdist/te
x/latex/bbm-macros/ubbm.fd) [1{/nix/store/wgpyg8ynf9nj2fldan5j6x9vz3ccswak-texl
ive-combined-2022/share/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 bbm10
mktexpk: /nix/store/5z8dbwcramqp6khals7x0k7z40c8q4fy-texlive-combined-2022-texmfdist/web2c/mktexdir ./.texlive2022/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm failed.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: /nix/store/wgpyg8ynf9nj2fldan5j6x9vz3ccswak-texlive-combined-202
2/bin/pdflatex (file bbm10): Font bbm10 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main.log' and/or above output for details

Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
```

I don't find the error `mktexpk: [...]/mktexdir [...]/bbm failed.` very enlightening.
Any help in debugging will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what packages are necessary to fix this but switching to `scheme-medium` fixes it.

Comment: Also this seems to be related to `pdftex` since compilation without the `-pdf` flag works.

Comment: Related: [Problem with bbm font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448413/problem-with-bbm-font-fatal-error-occurred-no-output-pdf-file-produced)